# Identifying a balanced smash product of G-spaces

Tags: general-topology, equivariant-topology

Let $X$ be a pointed $G$-space, why is it true that  there is a natural isomorphism $G_+\wedge_HX≅G/H_+\wedge X$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$? (Maybe some assumptions are needed on $H$, in which case, let me know!)